# How to index documents automatically once added in Firestore according to a Field?

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore, google-cloud-functions

I am making something like a **leaderboard** using **firestore** , So I want documents  of the Result collection to be indexed **automatically** in the database not on the client according to **Time**DESCENDING so that it will be shown in the client side which is an android app

My firestore database looks like this:

```
   Results:------------------------>(collection)

          {bcmskdjdkd}:------------->(document)
                     Time:22.3------->(Field)
          {trhrthrtht}:
                     Time:21.5
          {xfgndrghnt}:
                     Time:24.6
```

Answer (score 0):

If your query using the field in question doesn't generate an error, then there is no need to create any indexes.  Firestore simply does not perform queries that it can't satisfy efficiently.

[Please read the documentation to understand Firestore indexes.](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing)

> All document fields are automatically indexed, so queries that only use equality clauses don't need additional indexes. If you attempt a compound query with a range clause that doesn't map to an existing index, you receive an error. The error message includes a direct link to create the missing index in the Firebase console.